# what is best way to keep track of changes made in wordpress website?

Tags: functions, admin, security, plugin-recommendation

I have a website which has many admins. What is the best plugin or any other functions which would do this work? Any suggestion would be a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many plugins that display the history of changes made by site's users.

Personally, I have used [Simple History](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-history/) plugin. It is easy to use, have a clear interface and useful log searching capabilities.

For the list of similar plugins, you can read [this recently updated article](https://wplift.com/wordpress-event-tracking) on wplift.